# What is visualforce for?

Tags: visualforce

Hi guys :) My questions are:

1. What is visualforce for?
2. Are aura components not enough to create an application?
3. How do I integrate aura component with Visualforce?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFSE. I'm glad to see that you've received some helpful answers, but just wanted to draw your attention to our [ask] page. We request that posts focus on one, clearly defined issue, drawing on your research so far. The best resource for getting started is Trailhead, which covers Visualforce, Aura, the newer Lightning Web Components, and integration between these technologies.

Answer (score 5):

*This is an opinion-based response which bends the guidelines for this site, so ignore as you wish. What follows is my perspective of the technologies, based on several years of using each.*

Visualforce is Salesforce's traditional web solution for when you needed to provide user experience that wasn't available out-of-the-box. It included some support for AJAX via VFRemoting but was slow and clunky. This was, in part, because the server side controller's state was continually serialized to and deserialized from the client (web browser) to allow the page to maintain state "on the server side".

Aura was Salesforce's first attempt as providing a modern web solution, much more focused on AJAX with components that asynchronously communicated with the server. Salesforce's Lightning Experience was built from various Aura components fitted together to create Lightning Pages. You could mix standard components with custom ones to allow a customized user experience without having to write everything used in a page. The UI was more responsive due to the way that components were more independent and were able to communicate more efficiently with the server using concurrent, async communications. However the Aura framework suffered from various performance issues due to the way it was built (including the way the view and model had automatic synchronization).

Both of these technologies have been superseded, to a large extent, by LWC. Lightning Web Components replace Aura components and use up-to-date techniques and technologies to deliver light-weight and effective components that can be used to build Lightning Pages. Salesforce provides a large catalogue of out-of-the-box components that you can use directly in Lightning Pages but also as components within your own bespoke components. Like Aura, LWC allows you to compose pages from a mix of OOTB and custom components, again allowing you to have a bespoke UX without writing all the stuff yourself. Depending on how you write your LWCs, these can be re-used across many different pages.

Out of the three technologies LWC is by far the most superior. It is quite light-weight and easy to learn yet very capable. It does have some specific restrictions (such as currently not allowing you to restyle OOTB components, though this can be argued as a good thing since it ensures consistency across the Salesforce UX) and doesn't support certain features available from Aura (such as having URL-addressable components or providing Action implementations).

If you are starting from a clean sheet, avoid entirely any Visualforce development (it is effectively dead technology) and use LWC everywhere you can, resorting to Aura only when essential. You can even avoid LWC in some cases, using Salesforce's screen flows to provide customized UX for performing specific processes.

If you are maintaining legacy Visualforce pages you can introduce use of Lightning components using Lightning Out, but my experience of this is that it is quite a lot of effort for little reward. Unless the Visualforce page is very sophisticated you'd likely be better off simply migrating it to Lightning, using standard and custom components as needed.

Comment: To say "avoid entirely VisualForce is not always feasible. Still the only way to connect UI to a Custom Button.

Comment: If you are using Lightning Record Pages you can drop an LWC control onto the page to provide a custom button. If you mean for overriding standard action buttons, you can do this using [aura](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/workshop-override-standard-action/override_4). Could you explain which type of button you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce is for creating views or pages which can augment or replace standard functionality provided by salesforce like layouts or to achieve a entirely custom functionality like a page which interacts with external system.

Aura components are enough for 99% of functionality. They were introduced in around 2016 or maybe before and help you build functionality using client-server architecture. I think but in some cases you will need VF pages like custom authentication using form submission.

Aura components can be [embedded](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm) in VF pages. To commmunicate between two you can also use Lightning messaging service.